# Excluding a dependency in creating fat jar using SBT

Tags: sbt, akka, sbt-assembly

I am writing a akka application. While creating far jar of application , I dont want scala libraries to be packaged with the jar. My build.sbt looks as follows:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name :="akka-app",
    version :="1.0",
    scalaVersion :="2.10.4",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("sample.hello.HelloWorld")            
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.4" % "provided",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"

)

// META-INF discarding
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
   {   
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }   
}
```

But this sbt packages scala with jar. I want only `com.typesafe.config` library to be present in the jar. Any solution how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude Scala by modifying the option in the `assemblyOption` setting:

```
assemblyOption in assembly := 
  (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```